# Javascript form validation with Jquery decoration

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, validation

Please excuse my lack of javascript seasoning.  I currently have two parts to my validation:
1. functions that apply css decoration to the input fields and makes the div that contains the error message visible
2. a function that aggregates the above functions and is called in the form ie, **onSubmit="(return validate();)"**

I wish to fix two things:
1.  Refactor code so as to make it smaller
2.  FIXED with code update.  <del>Apply selector text decoration to all empty fields.  Currently, the decoration is applied to the first empty field then once a text value is entered, it hits the next field.  Every empty field should be validated and show proper decoration.</del>

```
/** VALIDATION DECORATION **/

function validateAccountNameRequired(textInputId, textInputLabelName) {
    var valid = true;

    if (!$('input#accountName').val()) {
        $('input#accountName').addClass('inputError');
        $('ul#accountNameList').find('div.error').attr('style', '');
        valid = false;
    } else if ($('input#accountName').val()) {
        $('input#accountName').removeClass('inputError');
        $('ul#accountNameList').find('div.error').hide();
    }
    return valid;
}

function validateAccountBusOrgIDRequired(textInputId, textInputLabelName) {
    var valid = true;

    if (!$('input#accountBusOrgID').val()) {
        $('input#accountBusOrgID').addClass('inputError');
        $('ul#busOrgList').find('div.error').attr('style', '');
        valid = false;
    } else if ($('input#accountBusOrgID').val()) {
        $('input#accountBusOrgID').removeClass('inputError');
        $('ul#busOrgList').find('div.error').hide();
    }

    return valid;
} /** VALIDATORS **/

function validate() {

        valid = validateAccountNameRequired('accountName', 'Account Name');
        valid1 = validateAccountBusOrgIDRequired('accountBusOrgID', 'Account Bus Org ID');

    return valid && valid1;
}
```

Comment: I know this isn't going to answer the question for your current solution, but why not think about switching your validation to make use of the jQuery validate library? It's much easier than trying to roll your own, and does all of the stuff you're trying to do with yours (as far as I can tell). If you'd still prefer to roll your own let me know and I can take a closer look at what you're doing, but I highly recommend using this one: [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: As stated below, you should be using the [Validator Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) which already does what you want plus a whole lot more.  It also includes a method called `.valid()` which eliminates the need for your "valid flag" variable.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my own issue.  Hopefully someone else can benefit:

1. Validates all fields at once
2. Refactored for better cohesion, just load values in function validate() and reuse one function validateTextRequired():

```
    function validateTextRequired( textInputId, errorListId)
        {
            var valid = true;
```

if( !$('input' + '#' + textInputId).val())
        {
            $('ul' + '#' + errorListId).find('label').addClass('error');
            $('input' + '#' + textInputId).addClass('inputError');
            $('ul' + '#' + errorListId).find('div.error').attr('style','');
            valid = false;
        } else if ($('input#' + textInputId).val()) {
            $('ul' + '#' + errorListId).find('label').removeClass('error');
            $('input' + '#' + textInputId).removeClass('inputError');
            $('u' + 'l#' + errorListId).find('div.error').hide();
        }
        return valid;
    }

           function validate()
           {
        valid = validateTextRequired( 'accountName', 'accountNameList');
        valid1 = validateTextRequired( 'accountBusOrgID', 'busOrgList');
        valid2 = validateTextRequired( 'acctMgr', 'accountMgrList');
            }

Comment: `if( !something ) ... else if (something) ...` is redundant. 
It is enough to write `if( !something ) ... else ...`. unless `something` calculation has no side effects.